# Mobiscroll with long/variable height, wrapping text options

Tags: mobiscroll

I'm looking to use Mobiscroll as a picker interface where it'd be perfect (using the custom image/text route where I'm loading a custom wheel).  The only issue is that the text options I have are long sentences and so I'd like to see if there's an easy way it to dynamically handle variable-line/height text.

I have a partial solution of modifying the min-height to max-height (otherwise the wheel keeps expanding), removing the nowrap from the li, and modifying the highlight-bar height and the height/line-height to the maximum length, but I'm wondering if anyone's' come up w/ a better/more elegant solution?